# sctp_connectx() gives EINVAL on FreeBSD

Tags: c, freebsd, sctp

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr;

    int clientSock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_SEQPACKET,IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if(clientSock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(&remoteAddr,0,sizeof remoteAddr);
    remoteAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remoteAddr.sin_len = sizeof remoteAddr;
    remoteAddr.sin_port = htons(5555);
    remoteAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sctp_assoc_t assoc_id = 0;
    if(sctp_connectx(clientSock,(struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddr,1, &assoc_id)!= 0) {
        perror("sctp_connectx");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected! Assoc ID %d\n",(int)assoc_id);

    return 0;   
}
```

When run, this code fails:

```
$ clang  -Wall sctp_connect.c 
$ ./a.out 
sctp_connectx: Invalid argument
$ uname -rp
11.0-RELEASE-p9 amd64
```

But I cannot figure out what's wrong. The [sctp_connectx](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sctp_connectx&manpath=FreeBSD%208.0-RELEASE)() manpage says it will fail with EINVAL if an address with invalid family or no addresses was provided  - but that seems not to be the case from the code.

The [sctp_connectx](https://github.com/moe123/mirroring-freebsd-github/blob/44078c2c278acced83d13b54414f8d918a0e5174/lib/libc/net/sctp_sys_calls.c#L100)() has several parts where it can fail with EINVAL, but `truss` shows it gets to the setsockopt() call, so it's the kernel that fails the call:

```
socket(PF_INET,SOCK_SEQPACKET,132)       = 3 (0x3)
mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34374418432 (0x800e00000)
setsockopt(0x3,0x84,0x8007,0x800e16000,0x14)     ERR#22 'Invalid argument'
```

Comment: a good [mcve]... the good output... try to solve this problem alone... why this question has no up vote ?

Comment: The man on linux said "EINVAL Invalid port or address.". Hope this help.

Comment: Conectx implies it's a 1:1 interface?  I think you can't use `SOCK_SEQPACKET` type of socket here you need to use `SOCK_STREAM`?

Comment: @Stargateur  It does not help. The very same code works fine on Linux.

Comment: @amritanshu Same problem if using SOCK_STREAM,

Comment: yeah, actually I don't have a freebsd setup mostly on linux and was trying to extrapolate things to help you, note I dont get an EINVAL on linux for your code.  Moving ahead, the call to setsocketopt will map to sctp_do_connectx in sctp_usrreq.c, one of the reason this call to connect can fail (with EINVAL) is if SCTP_REUSE_PORT is not enabled for the socket.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. But I have slightly different version of FreeBSD :( michalo@darkstar:~/src % ./a.out
Connected! Assoc ID 3
michalo@darkstar:~/src % uname -rp
10.3-RELEASE-p11 amd64

Comment: try to find out is your address is valid? print address after convert it to string ba2str()    it seem you are not use true argument     https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sctp_connectx&manpath=FreeBSD%208.0-RELEASE

Comment: http://petanode.com/blog/posts/sctp-specific-socket-functions-in-linux.html

Comment: @binary01 I have faced the same issue, have you find the resolution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think answer is there in your query. If we follow the `truss` trace then as you said it fails on `setsockopt()`.

So the error **EINVAL** is returned by `setsockopt()`. And as per FreeBSD `setsockopt()` manual:

> [EINVAL]: Installing an accept_filter(9) on a **non-listening**
> socket was attempted.

is the description of the error. So I think you should do below things:

1. Explore your socket options whether they are correct with respect to you listener socket.
2. Check for the errors for functions `htons()` and `inet_addr()`

And my suggestion is that you should not use inet_addr(), for more details see man pages, as per that:

> Use of this function is problematic because -1 is a valid address
> (255.255.255.255). Avoid its use in favor of inet_aton(),
> inet_pton(3), or getaddrinfo(3), which provide a cleaner way to
> indicate error return.